# How do I create geometric shapes like that?? (picture included)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm having difficulties trying to create perfectly align shapes like that using photoshop.

[image]

I'm not sure how I can achieve that, i can create one simple + shape using rectangular marquee tool, but how can I multiple it and align all the copies?

Answer (score 2):

Create the white plus sign and define a Pattern with a bigger selection mark

[image: Pattern]

Fill an empty layer over the image with the pattern

[image: FILL]

Photo from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/TtP9IVxxvD0)

Comment: thank you, I was able to do it but it;s not align to the frame like yours https://i.imgur.com/60G44nPg.png

Comment: Move the layer to adjust